# How to deduce a result assuming prime number theorem

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, chebyshev-function

I am unable to derive this result assuming prime number theorem. Can someone please tell how to do it.

Edit -> Here is a proof from stackexchange >but I couldn't think how last line is true. Can someone please  tell how it's true

> If $d_n = \text{lcm} \{1,2,3,... n\}$ then prove that the prime number theorem implies $$\lim _{n\to \infty} \frac {\log(d_n)} {n} =1$$

[image]

Can someone please tell how to derive it.

Comment: Where do you get stuck when you try? Adding that detail will mean that people can help you get unstuck

Comment: [This duplicate](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/217845/asymptotics-of-the-least-common-multiple-of-the-first-natural-numbers) appeared on math overflow (the question concerns the limsup by the answer looks at the limit).

Comment: @lulu can you please tell how to prove lcm(1, 2,...,n) = $ e^{\psi(n) }$

Comment: @lioness99a can you please see the question now and give some hint if you have spare time for that

Comment: @lulu please see edit and can you please tell how to prove it

Comment: @lioness99a both the user which asked and answered are not user of site anymore so I can't ask them , can you please help if you have some spare time

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function

Comment: @Will Jagy on Wikipedia it is just written that this property holds. I have already done a google search. Can you please give some hint!!

Comment: @lulu can you please explain my  question?

Comment: @invisible man. Answered bellow. you still have questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with

[$lcm(1,2,3,...,x)= \prod\limits_{p\leq x} p^{max(\nu_p(1),\nu_p(2),\nu_p(3),...,\nu_p(x))}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple)

Since $$max(\nu_p(1),\nu_p(2),\nu_p(3),...,\nu_p(x))$$ is the maximum exponent of $p$ you'll find in numbers $\leq x$, it is $\lfloor \log_px \rfloor$

$$lcm(1,2,3,...,x)=\prod\limits_{p\leq x} p^{\lfloor \log_px \rfloor}$$
$$\log lcm(1,2,3,...,x)=\sum\limits_{p\leq x} {\lfloor \log_px \rfloor}\log p$$
and with

[$\psi(x)=\sum\limits_{p\leq x}\lfloor \log_px \rfloor \log p $](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function) (see **EDIT**)

$$\log lcm(1,2,3,...,x)=\log(d_x)=\psi(x)=\log e^{\psi(x)}$$
$$lcm(1,2,3,...,x)=e^{\psi(x)}$$

and from $\log(d_x)=\psi(x)$ you have your result

---

**EDIT** (not clear enought in the link):

$\psi(x)=\sum\limits_{p^k\leq x}\log p$

Since the maximum exponent of $p^k\leq x$ is $\lfloor \log_px \rfloor$ you have $\lfloor \log_px \rfloor$ powers of $p$ in that range: $\{p^1, p^2, p^3, ..., p^{\lfloor \log_px \rfloor}\}$, so $\log p$ is counted accordingly for each $p$:

$\psi(x)=\sum\limits_{p^k\leq x}\log p=\sum\limits_{p\leq x}\lfloor \log_px \rfloor \log p $

Comment: accepted your answer but cannot read it now. Really busy in something. If I have questions, then I will ask you later when I read it in comments.

Comment: ok. no problem .

Comment: Apostol in introduction to analytic number theory writes $ \psi(x) $=$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{p\leq x^{1/m} } log p $ not what you wrote in edit. Can you please explain?

Comment: you wrote only 1 summation, there is no summation over k in your definition.

Comment: @Yannic Muller, That's the same. This notation (also used on the wiki page) means "for all power of $p$ not exceeding $x$" which you can write $p^k\leq x$ or $p\leq x^{1/k}$ (with a sum on $k$ if you want)

Answer (score -1):

Well, I don't know why you do not mention books, if this troubles you. Here is an excerpt from Ingham. On average, if a mathematics book is old enough you can find a "preview" online, and this may include pages discussing your interest.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I want to ask how $\psi(x) $  raised to power e equals lcm(1, 2,...n), how is that image related to the answer to this. Can you please explain

Comment: @InvisibleMan no, I am out of ideas. I do have a copy of Introduction to Analytic Number Theory by Apostol, which is intended for undergraduates. The presentation seems good, very basic. It certainly covers your question. He has the Mangoldt $\Lambda(n)$ function on page 32, then Chebyshev's second function $\psi(x)$ on page 75. That is one way you have  composed your question poorly, you never gave your own  definition of  $\psi(x).$ You have been asking people to write an entire book chapter or two for you.

Comment: no I was asking for only proof of this result. But it's fine.

Comment: can you please tell now, how can i prove it?